# How do I get my current page stylesheet as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say my current page looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
         /* I want to get all this as a string.. AS IS */
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
       function getEntireStyleAsString()
       {
              var str = "";
             /// .... what should be in here?
             return str;
       } 
       </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I'd like a simple function that returns my entire style of my page as a string. Using jquery is fine. I've been researching this for awhile and can't find the answer.

Comment: Is all of your styling in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>`?

Comment: What about other `style` tags?  Referenced style sheets?  Inline styles?  Non-CSS styling tags/attributes?  etc.?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the first stylesheet on the page you can use the following:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML;
```

However this will only get the code within that first style tag.

Comment: funny it's called innerhtml when there's no html in there

Answer (score 3):

If using jQuery is allowed, you can write something like this:

```
 var styles = $('style');
```

Which gives a jQuery selection of all styles on the document.
From here, you can do something like:

```
styles.text();
```

To get it all as a string. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the answer provided by **Peter Rasmussen**. But if you have more than one `<style>` tags in your `<head>` section, you would better use this to pull all styles:

```
var sts = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
var str = '';
for(i = 0; i < sts.length; i++){
    str = str + sts[i].innerHTML;
}
document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, nevermind.

```
<style id='test'>
</style>

$('#test').text()
```